# Android Studio 3.1.3 Preview screen blank

Tags: android-studio

im a total newbie to Android Studio. I know the blank Preview screen is a known issue. On another thread a solution was to change something called 'AppCompat'.

The solution given was as follows:

"Change AppCompat library version in Gradle :

From

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3' 
To

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
It Works !"

My question is, where do I find the AppCompat library version so that I can change this 1 line of code?

Many thanks

Fe